# Sorting table in R with specific string in field (r language)

Tags: r

I have my table(input):

```
     user_name    event_id  
1     "Joe"    Source:Coins:MinigameReward
2     "Tom"    Sink:Coins:EndSession
3    "Fred"    Sink:Tickets:StartGame
4     "Tom"    Source:Tickets:EndSession
5     "Joe"    Sink:Coins:EndSession
```

and I want to leave only rows that contain or `Source:Coins` or `Sink:Coins` in field `event_id`. The result (output):

```
     user_name    event_id  
1     "Joe"    Source:Coins:MinigameReward
2     "Tom"    Sink:Coins:EndSession
3     "Joe"    Sink:Coins:EndSession
```

`event_id` is character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(user_name=c('Joe','Tom','Fred','Tom','Joe'),event_id=c('Source:Coins:MinigameReward','Sink:Coins:EndSession','Sink:Tickets:StartGame','Source:Tickets:EndSession','Sink:Coins:EndSession'),stringsAsFactors=F);
df[grep('(Source|Sink):Coins',df$event_id),];
##   user_name                    event_id
## 1       Joe Source:Coins:MinigameReward
## 2       Tom       Sink:Coins:EndSession
## 5       Joe       Sink:Coins:EndSession
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what format your input is in, but for a dataframe you could use grep to find the index of matching strings.

```
df=data.frame(user_name = c("Joe" ,"Tom" ,"Fred"  ,"Tom"   ,"Joe"),"event_id"=c("Source:Coins:MinigameReward","Sink:Coins:EndSession","Sink:Tickets:StartGame","Source:Tickets:EndSession","Sink:Coins:EndSession"))

df[c(grep("Source:Coins",df$event_id), grep("Sink:Coins",df$event_id)),]
```